# DataGridView - Suppress string's cut off

Tags: c#, string, datagridview

I'm trying to resize a DataGridViewCell to smaller width than autosize does.

For example, in one column there is only "A" or nothing possible, but if I resize the column (doesn't matter if manually or programmatically) the string is "cut off" to "A...".

Is there a way to suppress that behaviour? I just want the "A" to fit exactly between the borders of that cell in order to provide the maximum amount of data possible.

Edit: Just to make my problem clear: autosize leaves a litle amount of blank space on every side of the column.

Comment: I guess you should try setting `dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells`

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I'm looking for. Autosized columns look quite nice but for me they take away too much space.

Comment: Are you sure that it's just `A`? I believe that you might have trailing blank spaces after `A`. Maybe you should trim the values before displaying them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should trim the values. Probably you have trailing white-spaces after `A`. Here's a short demo which explains the behavior:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = new[] { 
    new{A="A                "},
    new{A="A"},
    new{A=""}
};
```

After re-sizing, you'll see that only the first row has the trailing dots.

**Alternatively**, you may try to set the column's wrap mode, padding, alignment and width:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Padding =new Padding(0);
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = 
    DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = (int)this.Font.Size * 96 / 72;
```

Comment: You made my day!! WrapMode was 'nonSet'

Answer (score 0):

After give the datasource to grid.Please put this code to auto resize the cell width according to data.

```
dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill);
```

For Detail you can drill down in that link

[Reference link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158594.aspx)